# Crontab kill firefox processes

Tags: cron, automation

I want to make a crontab job for killing any firefox processes running, if there is more than a max number of processes running, starting with the oldest process.

So let's say 5 processes is running and I only wan't to allow a maximum of 2, then kill the 3 oldest automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set maximum amount of remaining firefox processes here
MAX_PROC=2

let COUNT=$(pgrep firefox | wc -l)
for (( i=1; i<=COUNT-MAX_PROC; i++ ))
do
  PID=$(pgrep -o firefox)
  kill $PID
# sleep 3
done
```

Comment: You can uncomment `sleep` line to add a timeout if this script is too fast and not killing processes as intended.

Comment: I've tried running this and it isn't killing the firefox instances; I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 - would that make a difference?

Comment: @HenryM Nothing special in 16.04, `pgrep` is the same. Does it kill anything? You can run `pgrep firefox` in terminal, then run my script and re-run `pgrep firefox`. Also bear in mind that this script will not close _all_ instances of FF, it will leave 2 of them - that was the OP task. If you wish to close all of them, the script should be modified.

Comment: I changed the line to `kill -o firefox` which is working fine.  Thanks

Comment: @HenryM Now that's interesting. `kill` has no `-o` option described in its manpage in 16.04 nor in older 12.04. `-o` option is valid for `pkill` and means _select the least recently started instance of the process_. Are you sure that `kill -o ...` doesn't complain in terminal regarding illegal option?

Comment: sorry @whtyger, it is `pkill -o firefox` I am using

Comment: @HenryM Good catch! Dunno why I used `pkill` where `kill` should be used. `pkill` closes processes by name, while `kill` closes processes by PID. Possibly I made a mistype and no one have noticed it. So this cycle should work in the following way: `pgrep -o firefox` finds PID of the oldest instance of Firefox and then `kill` terminates it. OR `pkill -o firefox` terminates oldest firefox instance in one step. Thanks for the idea. I'll update the script. I'll also add variable to set the number of remaining instances.